# CMake/CTest add_test command appends extra quotes to my command parameters

Tags: string, unit-testing, cmake, concatenation, ctest

In CMake I have a function:

```
function(add_mpi_test name no_mpi_proc)
  include_directories(...)
  add_executable(...)
  add_dependencies(...)
  target_link_libraries(...)
  # The important lines:
  set(test_parameters " -np ${no_mpi_proc} ./${name}")
  add_test(NAME ${name} COMMAND "mpirun" ${test_parameters})
endfunction(add_mpi_test)
```

that I use to create tests like this:

```
add_mpi_test(mpi 4)
```

But when I run CTest I get the following error:

```
2: Test command: /usr/local/bin/mpirun " -np 4 ./mpi "
2: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+06
2: [proxy:0:0@localhost] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:75): execvp error on file  -np 4 ./mpi  (No such file or directory)
```

However if I run in the directory

```
/usr/local/bin/mpirun  -np 4 ./mpi
```

without the quotes everything works, and if I run it with the quotes

```
/usr/local/bin/mpirun " -np 4 ./mpi "
```

I get exactly the same error.

- Is there a way to remove these quotes?
- What do I have to change in the line

  add_test(NAME ${name} COMMAND "mpirun" ${test_parameters})

to get:

```
2: Test command: /usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 4 ./mpi
```

without quotes?

I've tried

```
add_test(NAME ${name} COMMAND "mpirun ${test_parameters}")
```

but then it says in can't find my executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
set (test_parameters -np ${no_mpi_proc} "./${name}")
add_test(NAME ${name} COMMAND "mpirun" ${test_parameters})
```

Comment: The parameter `test_parameters` list needs to be built up as a CMake list not as a CMake string.